# Disable opening new window while playing a video in libvlc Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, libvlc

I'm working on video player and I was wondering how to disable opening and playing chosen video in new window? Is there way how to open it in original window? I have absolutely no idea how to do it. Thank you everyone.

[on left: original window;on right: additional window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIh3j.png)

```
import os, sys, pathlib, vlc
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class BaseTkContainer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk_instance = tk.Tk()
        self.tk_instance.title("py player")
        self.tk_instance.geometry("640x510")
        self.tk_instance.configure(background='black')
        # Create Control and Display panel
        controlFrame = LabelFrame(self.tk_instance,relief=GROOVE, bg='#383859')
        controlFrame.place(x=0, y=480, width=640, height=30)
        playBtn = Button(controlFrame, text="Play", command=self.PlayMovie, bd=0).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        stopBtn = Button(controlFrame, text="Stop", command=self.StopMovie, bd=0).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        pauseBtn = Button(controlFrame, text="Pause", command=self.PauseMovie, bd=0).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
        openBtn = Button(controlFrame, text="Open", command=self.OpenFile, bd=0).grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)
        testBtn = Button(controlFrame, text="Time", command=self.InfoDisplay, bd=0).grid(row=0, column=5, sticky=W)
        self.timeLabel = Label(controlFrame, font=("calibri",11,"bold"))
        self.nameLabel = Label(controlFrame, font=("calibri",11,"bold"))
        self.volumeScale = Scale(controlFrame, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.MovieVolume, sliderlength=15, bd=0, showvalue=0, length=200)
        self.volumeScale.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=W)
        self.volumeScale.set(50)

    def MovieVolume(self, setValue):
        """Volume settings"""
        volume = self.volumeScale.get()
        try:
            self.mediaPlayer.audio_set_volume(volume)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def PlayMovie(self):
        """Play a file"""
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
        self.mediaPlayerState = "State.Playing"
        self.InfoDisplay()

    def StopMovie(self):
        """Stop the player"""
        self.mediaPlayer.stop()

    def PauseMovie(self):
        """Pause the player"""
        self.mediaPlayer.pause()

    def OpenFile(self):
        """Open window explorer to select a movie to play"""
        file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        directoryName = os.path.dirname(file)
        self.fileName = os.path.basename(file)
        media = str(os.path.join(directoryName, self.fileName))
        self.mediaPlayer = vlc.MediaPlayer(media)

    def InfoDisplay(self):
        """Display basic info about a movie"""
        --snip--

root = BaseTkContainer()
root.tk_instance.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not told libvlc which window to draw into, it will create one himself and draw in that.

So if you want libvlc to draw in your designated window of your app, you need to tell it, depending on your host platform:

- `libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd` on Windows,
- `libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow` on Linux,
- `libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject` on Apple platforms.

For the exact documentation and parameters required, see the [official docs](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#ga0ee3abb85cd9735fdeace4882eb711f3). Since you're using Python, you should search in the bindings how these C functions are exposed from the Python bindings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But figure this out is way too difficult for me. I'll leave this project alone and move on to something else :)